# how to align thead and tbody of table in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am using struts2 framework. I need to align thead and tbody of table using javascript or jquery or any other.The table(thead and tbody) is dynamic.Please help.The number of columns may change according to need. here is code of jsp.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<s:div cssClass="tableClass" cssStyle="width: 100%; height:200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <table class="scroll table-striped" id="mail_table" style=" width: 98%;min-width: 1289px;overflow-x: scroll;">

        <thead>
            <tr style="background: #4A4747;"> 

                <th>Slno</th>
                    <s:iterator value="reportDataHeaderDtl" status="head">                              

                    <th style="width:<s:property value="%{report_attributes.get(#head.index).report_header_width}" />%;word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-all;white-space: nowrap;vertical-align: bottom;"><s:property value="%{reportDataHeaderDtl.get(#head.index)}" /></th>
                    </s:iterator>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody style="border: 1px solid #e0e0e0; border-radius: 3px;" id="mail_tbody">
            <s:iterator value="reportDataDtlList" status="head">
                <tr>

                    <td ><s:property value="%{#head.count}"/></td>
                    <s:iterator value="%{reportDataDtlList.get(#head.index)}" status="inhead">
                        <td style="padding: 5px;width:<s:property value="%{report_attributes.get(#inhead.index).report_header_width}" />%;word-wrap: break-word;word-break: break-all;vertical-align: bottom;"><s:property value="%{reportDataDtlList.get(#head.index).get(#inhead.index)}"/></td>
                    </s:iterator>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</s:div>
```

Comment: Question: how are the *not* being aligned?

Comment: @Roman C : This table will be attaached in the textarea. When any of cell(td) in tbody is null, it takes less space than its heading(th)

Comment: Use the same space, by default cells are aligned left. How do you want to align them?